# Setting XML Namepaces

Tags: c#, xml

I want create an xml document with the namepace attributes along the lines of this:

```
<MyXmlDoC xmlns="http://abc" xmlns:brk="http://123">
```

Using the System.Xml.Linq xml library, iv done this:

```
     public static XAttribute XmlNamepace()
        {
            return new XAttribute(XName.Get("xmlns"), "http://abc");
        }

        public static XAttribute brkNamepace()
        {
            return new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "brk", "http://123");
        }

 var rootNode = new XElement("MyXmlDoC",XmlNamepace(),brkNamepace());
```

But this produces this error:

> The prefix '' cannot be redefined from
>   '' to 'http://abc' within the same
>   start element tag

What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(From your answer) you need to add the ChildNode with the rt namespace, this should work:

```
rootNode.Add(new XElement(rt + "ChildNode", "Hello"));
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, you deserve an accepted answer, but this techically doesnt answer my orginal question

Comment: I think it's the same issue, you're not setting the namespace correctly.